# Solr single word search not giving exact result

Tags: solr

Using Solr 8.11.1. Added title, description, and company name as a String type in Jobs core. Made 'tdc' copyField in 'text_en' type. Using AND condition in q.op param. if I search 'PHP developer' means it gives the exact result, but if I search 'developer' alone it fetches a lot of results that contain 'develop'. I need the exact result of 'developer'.

This is my query

```
cat:JOB AND tdc:("developer")
```

Comment: what field type is defined for teh field tdc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text_en field type uses the solr.PorterStemFilterFactory in it.

`solr.PorterStemFilterFactory` : This filter applies the Porter Stemming Algorithm for English.

For eaxmple if your field type is like below with `PorterStemFilterFactory`.

```
<analyzer type="index">
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory "/>
  <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

your input for indexing is : **"jump jumping jumped"**

Tokenizer passed to Filter is : **"jump", "jumping", "jumped"**

the end Output is : `"jump", "jump", "jump"`

If you don't want stemming then you may need to remove this `PorterStemFilterFactory` from you field type definition and re-index the data.

Same is happening in your case for the word `developer`.

And if you are looking for exact match you can use the  having a `KeywordTokenizer` with a `LowercaseFilter` as field type for your field.

```
<analyzer>
  <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

Comment: Great Thanks @Abhijit Bashetti. Single term is now working perfectly, but Group has broken. I searched "DevOps Engineer", It doesn't work, but it was working well before I made the changes.

Comment: @ammni, If you have used KeywordTokenizer with a LowercaseFilter as field type for your field it will work perfectly for single term as it will not create any token of the terms. But if you want multiple terms to match then use the earlier field type for your field by removing the PorterStemFilterFactory from filter.

Comment: .. or add a new field that you use for exact searches in addition to the regular field, so that you don't break stemming functionality. You can use a copyField instruction to copy the same content into multiple fields and analyze it differently based on your needs.